# Elm: Search Number in Bytes

Tags: elm

I'm trying to find some exif data in an image.

So first I need to find the number `0x45786966` ('Exif' as unsignedInt32) and store the offset.

The next two bytes should be zeros and after that the endianness as unsignedInt16 (either 0x4d4d or 0x4949) which should be stored too.

I can get the image as `Bytes` with the `elm/file` module.
But how do I search the 'Exif' start and parse the endianness in those `Bytes`?

I looked at the [`loop`-example](https://github.com/elm/bytes/blob/1.0.8/src/Bytes/Decode.elm#L390) from `elm/bytes` but do not fully understand it.
First it reads the length of a list (unsignedInt32) and then it reads byte by byte?
How would this work if I want to read unsignedInt32s instead of bytes?

How do I set an offset to indicate where functions like `unsignedInt32` should read next?

Answer (score 1):

The example is talking about structured data with a known size field at the start. In your case, what you want to do is a search, so it is a rather different problem.

The problem is `elm/bytes` isn't really designed to handle searching. If you can guarantee the part you are looking for will be byte aligned, it may well be possible to do this, but given just what you have said, there isn't an easy way, as you can't iterate bit-by-bit.

You would have to read in values without alignment and then manually search for the part of the number you want within that. Given the difficulty and inefficiency of that approach, I would recommend using ports instead for that use case.

If you can guarantee that what you are searching for will be byte-aligned (or better yet, aligned to the length of your number), you can decode a byte at a time until you find what you are looking for. There is no way to read from a given offset, if you want to read to a certain point, you'd need to read and throw away values.

To do this, you would want to set up a loop where your state contains how much of the value you are looking for you have found. Each step, you check if you have the whole thing (success), you have the next part (continue), or you have something different (reset the state to search from the start again). If you reach the end without finding it, you have failed.